# Devise+OmniAuth for Facebook Sign Up on Remote Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I am using Devise + Omniauth to enable Facebook signup in my application. When I was developing it, I encountered no problems. Same with deploying it to my remote server. The problem is, other people keep encountering the same error:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
app/models/user.rb:67:in `find_for_facebook_oauth'
app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:4:in `facebook'
```

I have the following code for the User model `user.rb`:

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth( data, signed_in_resource=nil)
user = User.where(:email => data.info.email).first
unless user
  params =
    {  
      :user =>
      {
        :username => data.uid,
        :email => data.info.email,
        :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
        :user_profile_attributes => 
          {
            :first_name => data.extra.raw_info.first_name,
            :last_name => data.extra.raw_info.last_name,
            :remote_image_url => data.extra.raw_info.image,
          },
        :user_auths_attributes =>
        {
          :uid => data.uid,
          :provider => data.provider
        }
      }
    }
    user = User.create!(params[:user])
end
return user
end
```

Where line 67 is the `user = User.create!(params[:user])`

And `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`:

```
def facebook
# You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
@user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

if @user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
else
  session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
end
```

Where line 4 is `@user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])`

The server logs also show the GET parameters:

```
Parameters: {"code"=>"[some long string of number and letters]", "state"=>"[another string of numbers and letters]"}
```

Update:
The logger outputs the following for `request.env["omniauth.auth"]`:

```
#<OmniAuth::AuthHash credentials=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash expires=true expires_at=1401992074 token="*"> extra=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash raw_info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash email="*" first_name="*" gender="male" id="*" last_name="*" link="https://www.facebook.com/*" locale="en_US" name="*" timezone=8 updated_time="2014-04-05T09:29:22+0000" username="*" verified=true>> info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash email="*" first_name="*" image="http://graph.facebook.com/*/picture?type=square" last_name="*" name="*" nickname="*" urls=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash Facebook="https://www.facebook.com/*"> verified=true> provider="facebook" uid="*">
```

Update 2:
Logging the params[:user] provides the following values:

```
Params: {:username=>"*", :email=>"*", :password=>"iePVLt7XEWk4YwPjja6n", :user_profile_attributes=>{:first_name=>"*", :last_name=>"*", :remote_image_url=>"http://graph.facebook.com/*/picture?type=square"}, :user_auths_attributes=>{:uid=>"*", :provider=>"facebook"}}
```

Comment: please user logger for the data argument in method `find_for_facebook_oauth` and paste it here( use `*` for tokens and emails...).

Comment: Here is the data argument. I took the liberty of also removing the user's name and uid if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your params hash as below:

```
params =
    {  
      :user =>
      {
        :username => data.uid,
        :email => data.info.email,
        :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
        :user_profile_attributes => 
          {
            :first_name => data.extra.raw_info.first_name,
            :last_name => data.extra.raw_info.last_name,
            :remote_image_url => data.info.image ## Removed comma and updated the method
          },
        :user_auths_attributes =>
        [{
          :uid => data.uid,
          :provider => data.provider
        }] ## Enclosed within array [] brackets
      }
    }
```

Looking at the params hash given by you, I can tell that a `User` and `Profile` have a `1-1 Relationship` whereas `User` and `Auths` has a `1-M Relationship`. In that case, `user_auths_attributes` must be passed as an `Array`.

`TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)`

You were getting the above error because `user_auths_attributes` was being **interpreted as an array and not a hash.** So when Ruby saw params[:user][:user_auths_attributes][:uid] it was trying to take the last key and turn it into params[:user][:user_auths_attributes][0] or at least find some integer value it could be converted to index the Array.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it finally worked, although I am now encountering another error concerning validation about saving the user profile image.

Comment: Glad to help :) You can post another question with relevant data along with error log so some other experts could also help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found only this issue:

```
:remote_image_url => data.extra.raw_info.image # In data I see only data.info.image
```

replace with

```
:remote_image_url => data.info.image
```

But it is not a solution for your question.

Try to debug data from `params[:user]`. From exception it looks like that you use some Hash on property which is Integer.

Comment: I changed the code to your suggestion and also added the values produced by the logger for params[:user], but I did not find any questionable values.

Comment: try to call from console 
 
 User.create({:username=>"test", :email=>"test@test.sk", :password=>"iePVLt7XEWk4YwPjja6n", :user_profile_attributes=>{:first_name=>"test", :last_name=>"test lastname", :remote_image_url=>"http://graph.facebook.com/*/picture?type=square"}, :user_auths_attributes=>{:uid=>"1234567", :provider=>"facebook"}}) or write tests. How do you handle `user_profile_attributes` and `user_auths_attributes `? In debugging try to remove all extra parameters and then increase its and find an error.